# eth.coinbase gives the wallet address which is not exist in the system

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain

I'm facing a strange issue, when I execute `eth.coinbase` command on Geth, it gives me wallet address which is not present in the key directory.

[image]

But that isn't in the genesis file

[image]

I'm not sure how this has been updated. Can coinbase update from web3js?

```
Version: 1.9.14-stable
Go Version: go1.14.2
Operating System: linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coinbase (also known as etherbase) can be configured from commmandline (`--miner.etherbase`) or from api call [`miner.setEtherbase()`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_setetherbase).

In a PoW blockchain it doesn't have to be an existing account, it can be any address.

Comment: I had idea of `miner.setEtherbase()` but not sure how the coinbase had been updated. Before it was `864093bb38b39bd718c6be71367e2d3873a81f7e`

Comment: @Div If you have the RPC port open and miner api enabled then someone might have changed it.

Comment: Okay, is there any method in web3 js from which anyone can change coinbase?

Comment: @Div If you have RPC access you can call [miner_setEtherbase](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Management-APIs#miner_setetherbase) without web3js.